# Count occurences of search term

Tags: c++, qt, search

I wish to count the number of occurrences of a given search term in a QPlainTextEdit in Qt.

I've tried using while (find()) to iterate through all occurrences, but performance is abysmal for any larger document and it locks the program for several seconds every time it attempts to perform a search.

```
int PlainTextSearch::countOccurrences(QString term)
{
    int occurrences = 0;

    QTextCursor searchCursor = textEdit->textCursor();
    searchCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
    textEdit->setTextCursor(searchCursor);
   
    // Moves the searchCursor to the term
    // True for as long as the term is found
    while(textEdit->find(term)) {
        ++occurrences;
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any other way of doing this than using find(), which is where the performance bottleneck appears to be.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **QString::count()** function.

Here is a solution based on your code (I haven't compiled it, it might contain typos) :

```
int PlainTextSearch::countOccurrences(const QString& term)
{
    return textEdit->toPlainText().count(term);
}
```

I haven't measured its performance but I suspect it will be faster than your solution.